# Any help on installing themes for Conky?

Tags: 15.10, themes, conky

I'm trying to install [a theme](https://github.com/zagortenay333/conky-Vision) for Conky, but the instructions are unclear.
It says to put *.conky-vision-icons* and *.conkyrc* into the ~ directory.

But where is **~**? I have unhid the folders but there's still no ***~***.

Any ideas?

Comment: ~ is /home/"Yourusername"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

~ refers to your home directory.  if your username is algonquin, then /home/algonquin is equivalent to ~